# Tips for Making Particles move down Mesh

Tags: particles

I've got a problem I'm hoping someone could help with. I'm looking to emit particles from only a portion of a mesh, then to make the section that's emitting particles move down the mesh. That is, the mesh itself stays static but the part that's emitting particles changes - like this:

[image]

The reason for me doing this is I've got a 3D scan of someone's head which I'm planning to make melt - with the particles coming off the flesh as it 'burns' down... I thought I might be able to use shape keys but as far as I'm aware you can't keyframe them. :/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use a boolean modifier.

Comment: You can key frame Shape Keys. You right-click in the slider where it says "value" (after moving to another spot on the time line and setting the value to what you want of course), then choose "insert keyframe".

Comment: Ok sweet thank you! I will give these a go :P